# How to modulize my mongoose setup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This use of `db.model('Model_Name').find(...)` worked before, but I've since split my database, model and controllers up, so now it seems I need to change things around  Please help show where I'm going wrong:

**schema.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    display_name            : String,
    email                   : String
});

var ClientErrorsSchema = new Schema({
    datetime        : Number,
    msg         : String,
    url         : String,
    line            : Number
});

var users = mongoose.model('Users',UsersSchema);
var client_errors = mongoose.model('Client_Errors',ClientErrorsSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model;
```

**db.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var model = require("./schema.js");

var MONGO = {
    username: "admin",
    password: "***",
    server: 'localhost',
    port: '*****',
    db: 'db_name',
    connectionString: function(){
        return 'mongodb://'+this.username+':'+this.password+'@'+this.server+'/'+this.db;
    },
    options: {
        server:{
            auto_reconnect: true,
            poolSize: 20,
            socketOptions:{
                keepAlive: 1
            }
        },
        db: {
            numberOfRetries: 10,
            retryMiliSeconds: 1000
        }
    }
};

var db = mongoose.createConnection(MONGO.connectionString(), MONGO.options);

db.model = model;

db.on('error', function(err) {
    f.consoleLogger("DB connection Error: "+err);
});
db.on('open', function() {
    f.consoleLogger("DB connected");
});
db.on('close', function(str) {
    f.consoleLogger("DB disconnected: "+str);
});

module.exports = db;
```

**user.js**

```
var db = require("./db.js");
...
db.model('Users').find(...)
```

So using the `util.inspect`, I can see the db has all of the models, but the error I'm getting on the find is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'User' of undefined'`.

**UPDATE**

Toad22222 provided great advice, and the schema appears to be valid - but the queries are not working - neither `db.model.Users.find({...},function(err,data){...});` or `db.model.Users.find({...}).exec(function(err,data){...});` fires the callback.  I have put the same code in the `on('open')` event as well, nothing happens.  Hopefully someone can explain why.

All advice appreciated!

Comment: Since you're exporting `module.exports = mongoose.model;` then in user.js you should use `db('users').find...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out

```
module.exports = {
    User: users,
    ClientErrors: client_errors
}
```

instead of

```
module.exports = mongoose.model;
```

You want to be exporting the schemas you are creating, not the `mongoose.model` datatype.

Comment: Cheers Toad, this seems to now be back on the right track, you're right.  One issue remains now however; the object `db.model.User` seems valid, but using `db.model.User.find(...).exec(function(err,data){...})` seems to not fire the callback, any idea why?

Comment: It is now seem to be fixed -- I have reversed the order of loading so the `db.js` only runs a `connect` and exports the resulting object to `schema.js` - and the `user.js` to load the `schema.js`.  Happy days!